# How to connect to a remote ldap server to perform ldap search from Windows 10 OS?

Tags: ldap

I am new to Ldap. I'm using windows10 OS and I'm trying to connect to a remote ldap server in order to perform an ldapsearch operation. I have browsed about this but till now I have only come across very very complicated steps and I'm not sure if its the right way as well.
So can someone share the steps in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the an LDAP browser, such as the Softerra LDAP Browser.

https://www.ldapadministrator.com/softerra-ldap-browser.htm

Then you enter the URL and authentication data of the server where you want to connect and you're ready to browse the data.

You will probably pass a "bind DN" (which identifies the user) and the password of him.

Comment: What about to use CLI (Powershell) scripts/commands to perform such queries in a similar fashion to `ldapsearch` in `bash` scripting ?

Comment: Useful comment, thanks. They are a valid option too, of course. Not for beginners though if I may add.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend [`Apache Directory Studio`](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) that works pretty similar to any other kind of LDAP browse, such as the above mentioned `Softerra`.

However, on Wikipedia you can find an exhausting [List of LDAP software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LDAP_software).